# Default Submit for Approval button?

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, approval-process

I created a custom object. I have not created any approval processes for this object but for some reason, there's a `Submit for Approval` button showing up while viewing a record for this new object.

My other custom objects don't have this `Submit for Approval` button.

Anyone know why this button why this button shows up on one custom object, but not others, and NONE have approval processes associated with them?

As a side note, I did copy some fields from the `Contract` object into my new object using the META data XML in the Force IDE. I just copied the `<fields />` tags I needed. I also copied some `<layoutSections />` elements form the Contract layout as well. I doubt this has anything to do with it, but I suppose it could.

Comment: My first thought is that you accidentally copied the button over when changing the layout.

Comment: do you have multiple page layouts for the custom object - displayed based on recordtype and/or profile?  One of these must have had the button inadvertently added

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just experienced this issue recently, and I found a solution.

As mentioned in the comments, this button is defined in the Page Layout. All I had to do was edit the page layout file and add this line:

```
    <excludeButtons>Submit</excludeButtons>
```

Inside the `<Layout>` tag.
Hope this helps!